# Div doesn't fit to parent after add content

Tags: html, css

My problem is with child div.
I have code:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
<div class="logo"></div>

<div class="menulist">

<span><a href="#first">First</a></span>
<span><a href="#second">Second</a></span>
<span><a href="#third">Third</a></span>
<span><a href="#fourth">Fourth</a></span>

</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#menu{
width:100%;
z-index:998;
height:64px;
max-height:auto;
overflow-y:content;
position:fixed;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px black;

}

.logo{

height:100%;
width:70px;
background-color:red;
display:inline-block;

}

.menulist{
display:flex;
height:100%;
width:70vw;
background-color:red;
display:inline-block;
}



.menulist span a{
font-family: Segoe UI Light;
padding:0px;
margin:-50px;
position:relative;
height:32px;
font-size:30px;
display:inline;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Without any content on .menulist div this div is fit to #menu, but after add some span's he isn't in #menu (lower). Can you explain me why?
Here's Jsfiddle project:
https://jsfiddle.net/wd3tjgk8/3/

Comment: max-height:auto; ?? overflow-y:content; ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your Fiddle not only to achieve the desired effect, but to clean up your code a bit. Instead of using `inline` or `inline-block`, I float **everything** in `#menu` to the left with

```
#menu *{
    float: left;
}
```

By floating, you stop every element from having white-space and line-space. Besides that, I've removed the `span`s and some unnecessary mark-up.

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wd3tjgk8/7/).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align: top;` on `.menulist` to fix this: https://jsfiddle.net/wd3tjgk8/5/

```
.menulist {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70vw;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Why? `display: inline-block;` will position it in the middle if not set to top ;)